# Has no segue with identifier 'searchSegue' through xib file's class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I am using a segue(`searchSegue`) to connect **my search screen** (`SearchViewController`) to **the search result page** (`PhotoStreamViewController`).

`SearchViewController` is a collection view. Every collection view cell has a design in Xib file. (Xib file's class is `SearchCategoryRowCell`)

Currently, when I triggered `searchSegue` through `SearchViewController` it works fine. But whenever I trigger the same segue through `SearchCategoryRowCell`, I am getting `Has no segue with identifier 'searchSegue'`

**SearchViewController.swift**

```
 class SearchViewController: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    ...
   func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchRedirect(keyword: searchBar.text!)
    }


    func searchRedirect(keyword:String) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchSegue", sender:self)
        PhotoStreamViewController.searchString = keyword
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
    ...
  }
```

**SearchCategoryRowCell.swift**

```
class SearchCategoryRowCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    //the method below is triggered by a click action  
    @objc func searchRedirection(_ sender:UIButton) {
        print("we")
        print(subCategoryArray[sender.tag].name)

        let searchViewcontroller = SearchViewController(nibName: "SearchViewController", bundle: nil)
        searchViewcontroller.searchRedirect(keyword: "otherSearchKeyword")

    }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
 let searchViewcontroller = SearchViewController(nibName: "SearchViewController", bundle: nil)
```

is not the currently presented VC , you have to use delegate or declare self as a property inside the cell class

```
class SearchCategoryRowCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  var sear:SearchViewController?

}
```

ans set it inside cellForItem in `SearchViewController`

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! cellClassName

   cell.sear = self

   return cell;

 }
```

//

then you can use the presented object

```
@objc func searchRedirection(_ sender:UIButton) {

    print("we")
    print(subCategoryArray[sender.tag].name)
    sear?.searchRedirect(keyword: "otherSearchKeyword")

}
```

Comment: That is a great solution. It worked perfectly. You are a lifesaver!

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

You've explained the reason perfectly. You are saying:

```
let searchViewcontroller = SearchViewController(nibName: "SearchViewController", bundle: nil)
searchViewcontroller.searchRedirect(keyword: "otherSearchKeyword")
```

So `searchViewcontroller` is a completely new view controller instantiated right there in your code. Thus, it has no segues. The view controller with the segues is the one *in the storyboard*, which is a completely different view controller.